# Cannot get the value of write-only property 'runProguard' with Gradle plugin 0.14.0 and Android Studio 0.9.0

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics

After downloading Android Studio 0.9.0 and after having it update the Gradle plugin to 0.14.0 I keep getting the following error whenever I try to build:

> Error:Cannot get the value of write-only property 'runProguard'

Below is the buildTypes from my Build.gradle. I've tried deleting all of the proguard related lines and resyncing but nothing works. How can I get this error to go away?

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        //runProguard true
        //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        //runProguard false
        //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently it was a problem with the Crashlytics/Fabric plugin. Update to version 1.14.3 in your dependencies classpath and it should work.

Source: https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/gvBK7fkYsR7

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to update to Fabric if you don't want, just update your crashlytics version to 1.14.3:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.14.3'
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to update the `dependencies { compile 'com.crashlytics'android:crashlytics:1.+' ..` part of the build.gradle file, only the `build script { dependencies { classpath ..` as @PaNaVTEC suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have got this error because you use Crashlytics. This solution was suggested by Andrei Verdes and allow you to use Crashlytics with AndroidStudio 0.9.0.

First of all you need to change current CrashlyticsAndroidStudioPlugin with a new FabricAndroidStudioPlugin. Go to [fabric.io](http://fabric.com) and upgrade crashlytics plugin and crashlitycs repos.
Fabric.io is the owner of Crashlytics, so all projects will be synchronized.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}       

dependencies {
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.0.1@aar'){
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```